# Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem

Tags: silverlight

I am getting a below error message in Silverlight application. Once I login to application and if I click on any tab I can see below error message.

Here is the error message:

> [Isolated storage init] Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.50918.00&File=mscorblib.dll&Key=IsolatedStorage_Init

Comment: Can you provide any source code? / is there a stack trace?

Comment: I don't have a code for this as I am not a developer. I am getting this error when I am trying to access the website. This is happening only with my machine and if I try to login from other machine with my User id and password then I am not facing this issue. Once I login to website and if I click on any tab I am seeing this error message. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies/browser cache?